# How to encrypt public key (X509 RSA 2048) in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, nodes, public-key-encryption

An example of the value of the CardData form element:

```
PAN=4300000000000777;ExpDate=0519;CardHolder=IVAN PETROV;CVV=111
```

The CardData object is collected as a "key=value" list (separated by ";"), encrypted
public key (X509 RSA 2048), the resulting binary value is encoded in Base64.

my code

```
const key = new NodeRSA();
key.importKey(this._publicKey, 'pkcs8-public');
const encrypted = key.encrypt(cardData, 'base64');
```

this._publicKey - Open code (X509 RSA 2048), for encryption, issued by a bank

```
Card data blocking error.
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `NodeRSA` as it is not maintained anymore. Instead, use the `crypto` package.

And this can be your function:

```js
function encryptWithPublicKey(publicKey, data) {
  const buffer = Buffer.from(data, 'utf8');
  const encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(
    {
      key: publicKey,
      padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING,
    },
    buffer,
  );

  return encrypted.toString('base64');
}
```

Comment: [Nest] 22891  - 04/21/2023, 1:55:04 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported
Error: error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported
    at Object.publicEncrypt (node:internal/crypto/cipher:79:12)